# AsyncResponder could not be found

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, flash

How can I import `mx.rpc.AsyncResponder`, in Flash cs6?

I had tried using the code below to import it:

```
import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;
```

Here is my error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 7 1172: Definition
>   mx.rpc:AsyncResponder could not be found.

I also tried the following code:

```
token.addEventListener(MySqlEvent.RESPONSE, onSqlResponse);

private function onSqlResponse(e:MySqlEvent):void {
    var statement:Statement = m_sqlConnection.createStatement();
    var token:MySqlToken = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable");
    token.addEventListener(MySqlErrorEvent.SQL_ERROR, onSqlError);
    token.addEventListener(MySqlEvent.RESULT, onSqlResult);
}
```

However, the listeners didn't get fired.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncResponder` is supported only for **Flex 3** and higher that's why it's unavailable in **Flash**, you should use an Flex IDE like **[Adobe Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html)**, **[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/)**, **[jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/flex_ide.html)** or [**eclipse** with FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download/) ... For more information about `AsyncResponder`, take a look here : [Adobe.com : AsyncResponder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AsyncResponder.html) and you can download [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) here.